Possibility of Co-simulation between Ignition Gazebo and Matlab/Simulink?
I would like to know this Co-simulation (Sending and reading commands from Simulink and the model is present in Ignition Gazebo) possiblity between Matlab/Simulink and new Ignition Gazebo. If anyone has tried it or have views on it. Please let me know.
I have already tried Co-simulation between normal Gazebo and Simulink. I do not have any resources explaining the Co-Simulation capability between Ignition Gazebo (new Gazebo) and Simulink

Welcome to Robotics, vbalaji21. As written, this question is off-topic. Can you please edit your question to make it a practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the Robotics question checklist for details of how to write a good question.

Specifically, I don't know what you mean when you say "co-simulation." Can you please clarify your use case, what you would like to do, what you've already tried, and what when wrong while you were trying it?

@Chuck I mean Co-simulation as having 2 simulation environment and running the same simulation. In my case, I intend to use Simulink and Gazebo. The simulink sends and reads commands and the model is actuated in Gazebo environment. I have tried an example of this between Old Gazebo (Gazebo 11) and Simulink (R2023b) and also saw examples online. I never found any resources or methods to do the same between Simulink and new Gazebo (Ignition Gazebo). I want to know specifically about the possibilities with new Ignition Gazebo / Gazebo Garden.

So to clarify, you want to have controllers running in Simulink (Matlab) and you'd like to test those controllers out in a physic robotics simulator (Gazebo). I believe that you are talking about this Mathworks tutorial here. In this case, Mathworks made an external gazebo classic plugin that was able to interface with Simulink directly. I do not know if they have made a plugin that is able to work with the new Gazebo (previously called Ignition) so that means you'll need to setup something yourself.
Here are several options:

Gazebo works with protobuf messages. If Matlab has a way to generate protobuf messages you'll might be able to interface directly with gazebo.
Gazebo has great ROS 2 integration with the ROS-gz-bridge. If Matlab has a ROS 2 interface then you can use that as the glue between Simulink and Gazebo.

Hope this helps to point you in the right direction!
Disclaimer: I'm not a maintainer of Gazebo and it has been over 7 years that I have worked with Matlab so my knowledge might be outdated.
